# What does Liu mean by "topological open/closed immersion" in his book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

In his book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves", Liu defines open/closed immersions of locally ringed spaces in terms of topological open/closed immersions:

[image]

What does he mean by the terms "topological open (resp. closed) immersion"?

Does he mean that

1. $f(X)$ is an open (resp. closed) subset of $Y\!,\,$ and
2. the induced map $X\to f(X); \;x \mapsto f(x)$ is a homeomorphism?

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's a correct definition. Yours (1.) is also equivalent to 2. below.

1. $f(X)$ is open (closed) and $f$ is a homeomorphism on its image
2. $f$ is open (closed) and a homeomorphism on its image

If we then define an *immersion* to be a homeomorphism on its image, then an open (closed) immersion really is an immersion that is open (closed).

**Note:** it is also called an *embedding*, which is safer to use than *immersion*, because it is closer to the terminology used in differential geometry.

Comment: This related MO question was helpful in connection with this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48527/why-open-immersion-rather-than-open-embedding